# How do I stop/compensate for a voltage drop across a transistor?

Tags: voltage, transistors, pulse

I have used a 555 timer to output a pulsed signal with amplitude 4.6V. I am then inputting this signal into a transistor to pulse an led. When I do this the amplitude drops to 0.8V. How can I stop this large decrease in amplitude?? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a resistor to drop the rest of the voltage.

Comment: Please add a schematic. There's a button on the editor toolbar and there's even a 555 timer in the symbol library.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you measuring this amplitude drop?

If you connected the 555 output directly to the base of the transistor, and the transistor's emitter is grounded, this drop is expected, and you are stressing the base-emitter junction of the transistor.

The base-emitter junction is effectively a diode and will hold the base voltage to about 0.7 volts above the emitter (depending on base current).  To avoid damage to the transistor, you need a resistor between the 555 output and the transistor base to limit current through the base-emitter junction.

Answer (score 1):

The amplitude you have observed (~0.8V, probably closer to 0.7 V) is given by your p-n junction between base and emitter. A p-n junction has a maximum voltage around that value because the voltage vs. direct current curve is a steep exponential - see the first quadrant of the figure below.

[image]

To get amplitudes greater than 0.7 V across a p-n junction means the need for a *huge* current, that your 555 simply is not able to provide, **and for all practical applications, it should be considered impossible to get 5 V across a p-n (base-emitter) junction.**

But this should not be taken as a *bad* thing (in fact, not at all!). What you need to do is as simple as getting your 5 V signal across the series of a resistor and the base-emitter junction, like the circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPACBW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any resistor value around the tens or hundreds of kilo is a safe bet. Best of wishes.